# Displaying directional bandwidths in QGIS

Tags: qgis, thematic-map

I have a traffic model and want to display the results in QGIS. I have a shapefile for the road network and can easily annotate the flows onto this. However, I want to display the information as bandwidths, separate by direction. I have tried this but the bandwidths for the two directions overlap.

Comment: Which tool are you using to produce bandwidths?

Comment: Use the line offset feature to draw forward direction lines on the right (positive offset) and backwards direction lines on the left (negative offset).